# Uploading files into shiny app and allowing the user to filter data for specific observations

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

How does one create a dynamic filter for the user to subset the data uploaded to their R shiny app?

The dynamic filter would change based on the previous filter in the sense that for example, once a Region has been selected, the following filters would update as necessary and only display further options to filter based on the region(s) selected. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The time series data set would look something like below:

```
Date    |    Region    |    Market    |    Product    |    SKU    |   Demand
01/01/18      Asia           Japan             A            1111         100
```

Comment: You have too many specifications and you haven't tried anything. It's hard to help in this situation

Comment: One can do this in shiny, but I would break this into smaller questions that people can answer.

Comment: @antonioACR1  thanks you for the suggestions. This was my first ever stack overflow question so the feedback is helpful for next time I need a question answered. Anyways, I managed to solve the problem but any suggestions to improve the code are welcomed.

Comment: @IanWesley thank you for the suggestions.  The problems is solved but any feedback to improve the code is welcomed.

Comment: @mlombera94 Yes, a suggestion for next time you ask something is to provide reproducible data and simplify your problem as much as possible. For example, how are we supposed to provide an answer like the one you posted if we don't even know that you have columns named "level0","level1", etc? We don't know that you have null values in your dataset either, and as someone pointed out before, for a task which should satisfy several needs, it's better to break it into smaller questions.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. Thanks for the feedback on my first stack overflow question. Will definitely keep those suggestions in mind next time I post a question. Any questions about the code below, feel free to leave a comment.

```
server <- function(input,output,session) {

### READ IN CSV FILE BASED ON SELECTION ###
mySeries_raw <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$i_file

    if (is.null(inFile)){return(NULL)}
    df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath,
                   header = T,
                   strip.white=T,
                   stringsAsFactors=F,
                   fill=T)

# Rename columns
df %>% setnames(old = c("SDATE", "LEVEL0", "LEVEL3", "LEVEL5", "LEVEL6", "SDATA4"),
                new = c("Date", "SKU", "Product", "Market", "Region", "Ship_AC"))

# Convert Date variable from chr to Date
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%d-%b-%y")

# Convert any remaining character variables to factors
df[sapply(df, is.character)] <- lapply(df[sapply(df, is.character)], as.factor)

# Drop observations containing observations from regions 177899, 234601, 236273, 250900, 29437 and filter observations that exceed current date
df <- df %>%
  filter(!Region %in% c("177899", "234601", "236273", "250900", "29437"),
         Date < as.Date(Sys.Date() %m-% months(1)), # Remove data that exceeds the current month 
         !is.na(Region),
         !is.na(Market))

# Remove "-" and replace with "_" as the "-" causes error later on
df$SKU <- gsub('-', '_', df$SKU)

return(df)

})

### BUILD DATAFRAME ###
# Create Select option for all regions available in the data
output$region <- renderUI({
data <- mySeries_raw()

if(is.null(data)){return(NULL)}

selectInput(inputId = "region",
            label = "Select Region",
            choice = unique(data$Region),
            multiple = TRUE)
})

# Filter the raw data based on regions selected
region_df <- reactive({
data <- mySeries_raw()

if(is.null(data)){return(NULL)}

data %>% 
  filter(Region %in% input$region)

 })

# Create select option for all markets available in the regions selected in previous filter
output$market <- renderUI({
data <- region_df()

if(is.null(data)){return(NULL)}

selectInput(inputId = "market",
            label = "Select Market",
            choice = unique(data$Market),
            multiple = TRUE)
})

# Filter the previous dataset of selected regions based on markets selected
market_df <- reactive({
data <- region_df()

if(is.null(data)){return(NULL)}

data %>% 
  filter(Market %in% input$market)
})

# Create select option for all products available in the markets selected in previous filter
output$product <- renderUI({
data <- market_df()

if(is.null(data)){return(NULL)}

selectInput(inputId = "product",
            label = "Select Product",
            choice = unique(data$Product),
            multiple = TRUE)
})

# Filter the previous dataset of selected markets based on products selected
product_df <- reactive({
data <- market_df()

if(is.null(data)){return(NULL)}

data %>% 
  filter(Product %in% input$product)
})

# Create select options for all SKUs in the products selected in previous filter
output$sku <- renderUI({
data <- product_df()

if(is.null(data)){return(NULL)}

selectInput(inputId = "sku",
            label = "Select SKU",
            choice = unique(data$SKU),
            multiple = TRUE)
})

# Filter the previous dataset of selected products based on SKUs chosen and build the dataframe based on the action button "Build Dataset"
final_df <- eventReactive(input$build, {
data <- product_df()

if(is.null(data)){return(NULL)}

# Drop the Product column
data <- data[, -which(names(data) %in% c("Product"))]

subset_data <- data %>% 
  filter(SKU %in% input$sku)

# Gather, unite and spread variables to include one column for the demand of each SKU in each Market for all Regions 
subset_data <- subset_data %>% 
  my.spread(key = c("Region", "Market", "SKU"), value = c("Ship_AC")) %>% 
  pad(interval = "month") # pad() function from padr library thats adds missing dates to time series data

# Add index to each row 
subset_data$id <- 1:nrow(subset_data)
subset_data <- subset_data

return(subset_data)
})

# Render the final filtered dataset
output$subset_df <- renderDataTable({
final_df()[, -which(names(final_df()) %in% c("id"))] # Drop id column to prevent from rendering. I used DT::renderDataTable to output the final dataframe
})
}

# Function to Gather, unite and spread 
my.spread <- function(df, key, value) {
# quote key
keyq <- rlang::enquo(key)
# break value vector into quotes
valueq <- rlang::enquo(value)
s <- rlang::quos(!!valueq)
df %>% gather(variable, value, !!!s) %>%
unite(temp, !!keyq, variable) %>%
spread(temp, value)
}
```